# "Ambient homotopy" between preimages under a fiber bundle?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, fibre-bundles

Choose a notion of an "ambient homotopy" between maps of topological spaces. For example, say that two embeddings $Y \rightarrow X$ are ambiently homotopic if there is a path between them in the space of embeddings from $Y$ to $X$.

Q. Given a fiber bundle $p: E \rightarrow B$, and two ambiently homotopic maps $f, g : X \rightarrow B$, are pullbacks $X_f \rightarrow E$ and $X_g \rightarrow E$ of $f$ and $g$ along $p$ ambiently homotopic (modulo somehow identifying $X_f$ with $X_g$)?

If one takes $X$ to be the space with two disjoint points, then $X_f$ and $X_g$ both are two disjoint copies of the fiber of $p$, so they are homeomorphic. Using some homeomorphism to identify $X_f$ and $X_g$ and using the above definition of the ambient homotopy, what is the answer to the question?

For example, consider the Hopf bundle $S^3 \rightarrow S^2$. Take $X$ to be the two point set. Then the two pullpacks $X_f \rightarrow S^3$ and $X_g \rightarrow S^3$ will both be two linked circles in $S^3$. These are "ambiently homotopic".

More generally, how to define the appropriate notion of an "ambient homotopy" so that the question makes sense?

Comment: Something in your question does not parse for me.  The two pull-backs are maps $f^*p : E_f \to X$ and $g^*p : E_g \to X$ these are maps from two different spaces to $X$, so your definition of ambient homotopy does not make sense.

Comment: A priori, the pullbacks of *f* and *g* along *p* have  different codomains $f^*E$, $g^*E$.  To make sense of the question, one has to identify these somehow; one certainly can do so, since they’re pullbacks of homotopic maps into a bundle, but the answer may be sensitive to how one does so, and how nice your notion of ambient homotopy is.

Comment: I mean maps $X_f \rightarrow E$ and $Y_f \rightarrow E$ which by Peter's comment still have different domains. In fact the question subsumes defining the appropriate notion of the ambient homotopy.

Comment: I don't there there's any reasonable (geometrically interesting) definition where your question would have an affirmative answer.  Let $p$ be the double cover of the circle.  Let $f$ and $g$ be maps from $S^0$ to $S^1$, one being a constant map and the other giving antipodal points.   Any isomorphism of the pull-back's domains require choices that can not be done by some single isotopy in the target circle.  You can compound this example by letting $f$ and $g$ have higher-dimensional domains.

Comment: @RyanBudney: if $f, g$ are supposed to be embeddings, then that rules out the constant map.

Comment: There is a notion of when maps $f: Y\to X$ and $f': Y'\to X$ are *homotopically equivalent*. This means there is a homotopy equivalence $h: Y\to Y'$ making the evident triangle commute. I think that is the best you can hope for here.

Comment: Now that the question has been changed, the answer is yes. If $f_t$ is an isotopy between $f$ and $g$ (say $f_0=f, f_1=g$) then $X_{f_t}$ will embed for each $t$. By homotopy invariance of bundles, for each $t$, $X_{f_t}$ is equivalent to $X_f$ as a bundle over $X$. The choice of identification is a choice of isomorphism between the pullback via the isotopy and the bundle $X_f \times[0,1]$.

Comment: @GustavoGranja Can you add more details?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: but it will certainly fail for embeddings also.  For example, a 1-parameter family of embeddings usually does not come from an ambient homotopy (ambient isotopy in the topological category).  For example, co-dimension two knots can all be "pulled tight" into unknots, via 1-parameter families of embeddings.

Comment: @Ryan Budney: I don't think the OP is using "ambient homotopy" in any technical sense.

Comment: @RyanBudney Yeah, I did not mean anything specific by the "ambient homotopy". Your argument however shows that the answer is negative when one choses it to be the ambient isotopy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment above was a bit rushed, sorry. Let $H \colon X \times [0,1] \to B$ be a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ and consider the pullback $(X \times [0,1])_{H}$ of the bundle $p$ along $H$. The pullback comes with a map 
$$ (X\times[0,1])_{H} \xrightarrow{\phi} E $$
covering the homotopy $H$. If for each $t$, the map $x \mapsto H(x,t)$ is an embedding, the restriction of $\phi$ to the bundle over $X\times\{t\}$ is also an embedding.

In any case, the point is that $(X\times [0,1])_H$ is isomorphic as a bundle to the product map $X_f \times [0,1] \rightarrow X \times[0,1]$ (see for instance Theorems 9.6 to 9.8 in [Husemoller - Fibre bundles](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/husemoller), pages 51-52) hence $\phi$ is your desired "ambient homotopy".

A choice of isomorphism between $(X\times[0,1])_H$ and $X_f \times [0,1]$ gives you the way of identifying $X_f$ with $X_g$.